# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have an issue with some linq causing the following errors.

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.
>   The specified cast from a materialized 'System.DateTime' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.

These two errors occur in the same linq statement at around the same time, the statement is a query with a join and a couple of where params.

My research included data issues, but I cannot see from the data how that would occur, however I came across this.

[The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Guid' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542055/the-specified-cast-from-a-materialized-system-guid-type-to-the-system-int32)

implying a threading issue with ObjectContext

My code is is run from a service with the following settings

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

We recently had an increase in calls, i.e. we opened up the service to more users, possibly 3 times as many concurrent calls

My understanding of ServiceBehavior is limited (no, I did not write this code) so I want to confirm,

will my service generate multiple threads, and with ObjectContext not being thread safe will this cause the same issue as in the above link, i.e. multiple threads overriding each others db context.

Comment: Do you have this exception "sometimes" or always? Only in production or also in dev environment?

Comment: It happens sometimes only, and only in production, and when it happens it and a restart of IIS fixes it.

Comment: oh, and when it happens, it brings the service down, i.e. every call gets errors, almost like hitting a thresh hold and now all hell breaks loose